# Added project to VS2013 Solution but it won't get tracked in Git

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013

I have a repo with multiple projects, tracked by git.  I am working in a branch and I need to add a client library as a separate project to the solution (in the branch).  However, I can't get the new project to be tracked in git.  This is what I did:

- In my branch, cloned the library via ssh
- git add [foldername]
- Built the library and closed VS
- Opened Solution and added existing project
- Built everything
- Added a ref to the new library
- Made a change to some  code in the library
- git status

I get nothing to commit except the sln file.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you just add it directly through your github account (github for windows UI, or through the browser) then do a refresh of your connection to github in VS 2013?

Comment: Didn't think of this.  The folder does exist on github.com but it is unclickable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just setup the new directory directly in github via browser or Github for Windows, then do a fresh pull of your github folders into VS2013. That should resolve your issue. I've done that before on VS2013 and Eclipse IDE and it worked for me.